# On ssh connection console is looking different with different users. Why?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, console, user-profiles

There are two users on my remote machine. One is *olduser*, another one is *newuser*.
*Olduser* ssh console is working and looking differently than *newuser* connection.
There are two folders for each user in `/home/` directory, so probably *newuser* `.bash_profile` file is not working.

*Newuser* has been created by `useradd -m` command.
*Newuser* `/home/` folder is missing files: `.bash_history` `.ssh`
Is it related with my problem?

How to get different and automatic console modes for each user (without additional commands each time I log in)?

Comment: Why would you expect `.ssh` directory to be created? That's something each individual user must do.

Comment: @snapshoe: Hmm... `.ssh` directory maybe it's not very important, but probably `.bash_history` could be quite useful.

Comment: Then, run `bash`, and it will be created.

Comment: @snapshoe: What do you mean? I've got only ssh connection available and I'm connected with *newuser* account, but it's not creating `.bash_history` file. It's keeping somewhere my commands, but not in *olduser* and not in *newuser* `.bash_history` file.

Comment: @snapshoe Using the command `bash` is not changing anything, so this is confusing, but you don't have to be angry by that :) I just don't have so much experience like you. But OK, I've fixed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old user account likely has been set to use the *bash* shell, while the new one uses the default *sh*. Verify this using `getent passwd olduser newuser`, and if needed, change the shell using either `usermod -s /bin/bash newuser` or `chsh`.

Comment: Thank you. Very good solution. It's fixing my problem, but still I don't see `.bash_history` and `.ssh` files in `/home/newuser` directory.

Comment: `.bash_history` may be created by bash when it is run.  There are options to control its placement and naming.  Unless the user creates it themself, `.ssh` isn't likely to be created until ssh is used an a manner that requires it.